# Made insertion into an oracle database but found nothing

Tags: c#, database, oracle, insertion

I have tried as much to insert into an oracle database. but i found nothing in the database when i queried it. yet it returns no of isertions made into the database on every executenonquery.please find my code below

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO btable (CH_CODE, ME_NUM, CY_CODE, ER_CODE, SUB_CODE, _LIM, LIM__DATE)" +
    " VALUES ('" + int.Parse(rows["ch_code"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["me_numb"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["cy_code"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["er_code"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["Sub_code"].ToString()) + "','" + double.Parse(rows["_limit"].ToString()) + "'," + "to_date('" + usedate +"','dd/mm/yyyy')" + "')"; 

command = new OracleCommand(queryString, conn);
command.Connection = conn;

if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    command.Connection.Open();
}
//command.Connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    intResult++;
}
```

The connection string is

```
<add key="OraConnString" value="Data Source=testdr.world;Persist Security Info=False;user id=****;password=****"></add>
```

It was called in the program as

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OraConnString"]);
OracleCommand command;
```

The database is an oracle database

Comment: Why do you have two command.ExecuteQuery()s?

Comment: was checking the if the insertion was made. i had to include the first one when i thought i did not call ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: You also don't seem to have committed? Do you have autocommit set?

Comment: Please how do i commit. And do i commit after every insertion